# Put integer value in 2 bytes

Tags: java, int

I don't know, how to frame my question ( and hence unable to search properly but I tried my best )

How do I ensure that my integer takes two bytes. Basically I want to read a binary file and extract some data from the file. All of which I am successfully able to do . Now I need to use the data read from the binary file and create a string which will be read by another module . The module expects the data in the following form

```
(Start_Tag)(Lengthin2bytes)(data)
```

I extracted the `data` already and I now know its length . How do I ensure that it is put in 2 bytes ?

Pardon me I am unable to frame the question really well . But I hope the scenario is clear.

Comment: An `int` is 4 bytes. A `char` is 2 bytes.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Comment: Remember, an int is 4 bytes. If you put integer value in 2 bytes. It will lose precision

Comment: java short is 2 bytes

Comment: Depending on the source of the data you may need to look into order of bytes for the 2 byte integer.  In other words the least significant byte may be the first byte or the second byte depending on the order used by what ever produced the file.

Answer (score 0):

I did this :

```
int in = 212;
byte[] data = new byte[2];
data[0] = (byte) (in & 0xFF);
data[1] = (byte) ((in >> 8) & 0xFF);
return data;
```

Works nicely :-)

Comment: @DebobrotoDas I was wondering the downvote . well I dont want it to work for that case .  . 0 to 65535 is enough for me . Infact that itself is a big number as the buffer in which I need to push the data itself can hold not more that 2000 bytes . Hence i think for my case this should do :-)

Comment: There's no mention of 65536 range in the question.